# Creating custom twitter widgets

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter, widget

I've been having a look around and I cant seem to find any real **good** info on creating a custom twitter widget. When I say custom I mean designing a twitter widget from the UI side and then adding twitter functionality to it. In other words, create your own twitter widget.

Any good sites out there that anybody can point me to?
Thanks!

Comment: So do you want to just have existing CSS that's easy to customise? Or do you want to design one from scratch?

Comment: @Bernie I have a twitter widget design mockup that was done in photoshop. What my job is now is to write the html/css for it and add twitter functionality to it.

Comment: One more question, what functionality is said widget going to display?

Comment: @Bernie very simple really, obviously latest tweets (anything from 1 to 3), the time of the last tweet (e.g. "about an hour ago") and the users twitter avatar and name. And perhaps when the avatar is clicked on you get redirected to the users twitter profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thinks this site will help you.you can see some useful things here. 
  http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-create-an-advanced-twitter-widget/